# Script : Detect if OS is x32 or x64 bit and Download latest Oracle Java JDK 8

Tags: linux, windows, java-8, cross-platform, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to download `Oracle Java JDK 8` directly from the [official website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).

To understand, I mean `Java Development Kit (JDK)`, not the `Java Runtime Environment (JRE)`, which can be downloaded automatically [here](https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=242029_3d5a2bb8f8d4428bbe94aed7ec7ae784).

NOTE: I'm not asking about outdated java scripts that no longer working and/or openjdk or something like that. Please, if you want to quote from other posts from Stack Overflow or other site - please, provide valid information.

I'm working on a software updater that works on windows, but also on Linux (Ubuntu, MacOS X, Fedora, Bedrock, Arch etc.). As building the cli script, I saw that on Linux is easier to keep the software up-to-date using the repos whereas in windows you need to `login-and-download`.

I searched on internet about `software updater` for software/scripts to update java, like:

[chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) ;

[Powershell Java-Update](https://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/PowerShell_Java_Auto-Update_Script) ;

[GitHub Java-Update](https://github.com/auberginehill/java-update)

and found `incomplete list, only for jre or outdated software versions`.

**But, after searching `deeper`, I found this link that automatically downloads `Oracle JDK 8` without login in a chat fragment from a website.**

> @Hello Just pass the bundle id through their webapp api https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=242044_3d5a2bb8f8d4428bbe94aed7ec7ae784

**How that guy did that? And how to keep the `oracle jdk 8` to the latest version using `git ; python ; windows-powershell ; powershell-core etc.`?**

**And can someone explain me that direct download link?**

Comment: Be aware of two things: (a) Oracle changed their licensing terms for their *Oracle JDK* product for Java 8, now no longer free-of-charge when used for deployment, and (b) you can obtain implementations of Java 8 from other vendors. You might find your scripting technically easier if using [*AdoptOpenJDK*](https://adoptopenjdk.net). They offer [this API](https://api.adoptopenjdk.net) for JSON information about the AdoptOpenJDK releases and nightly builds.

Comment: Yeah, but adoptjdk isnt equal to oraclejdk. this is because: 1. Fewer GC options, ;and 2. slow renderer. And i dont think `adoptopenjdk` can handle old java  code, such as for running older minecraft versions